# Calling C++ dll in C# debug dll working but release dll not working

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have some c++ code that I'm calling from my c# code..

When I build the c++ dll in Debug mode calling the dll and getting it to return something works fine..

When I build the c++ dll in RELEASE mode calling the dll I get this error:
[image]

and pretty much no stack trace.. I'm printing out things in the c++ code to to try to verify that that's running.. and everything appears to print out fine..

C++ code:

```
    #define MyFunctions _declspec(dllexport)
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../DoorOpenerSketch/Desfire.h"
#include "../DoorOpenerSketch/DesFireKey.h"



extern "C" {

    

    MyFunctions int GetData(unsigned char data[], byte* dataFromCard)
{
    try
    {


        const int DES_SIZE = 16; 
        const int AES_SIZE = 16;
        Desfire i_Desfire;
        unsigned char u8_DataFinal[16];
    
        i_Desfire.Authenticate2(0, &i_Desfire.DES2_DEFAULT_KEY, dataFromCard, u8_DataFinal);


        int tlen = 3;


        
        memcpy(data, u8_DataFinal, sizeof(u8_DataFinal));



        return 1;
    }
    catch (char* p)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
}
  


    


}
```

C# code

```
      public const string CppFunctionsDLL = @"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Desfire.dll";

        [DllImport(CppFunctionsDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
     
    static extern int GetData(byte[] outPutData, byte[] dataFromCard);

  public static byte[] GetEncryptedAnswerForCardInCplusplus(byte[] initialResponseFromCard)
        {
            byte[] outPutData = new byte[16];
        var hr = GetData(outPutData, initialResponseFromCard);

        

        return outPutData;

        }
```

In the c# code it fails here:

```
 var hr = GetData(outPutData, initialResponseFromCard);
```

and like I mentioned before I can see "test this ran 90" printing out to the console

Comment: `unsigned char u8_DataFinal[16];` in GetData is a local variable. It does not continue to exist once GetData returns. `*data = u8_DataFinal;` is out of the question. You need a different method to communicate the information back to the caller. Either have the caller provide the memory buffer for GetData to fill or dynamically allocate it in a way that you can hand it back to the caller. I'm not up on the details of what mechanism would work in this situation.

Comment: @AviBerger why does the code work ok in debug c++ dll but not release c++ dll?

Comment: @user55665484375 -- Undefined behavior means just that -- the behavior is undefined.  It really does not "work" in debug.  You are just lucky (or maybe unlucky) that the behavior was one you expected in debug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok so what should I do?

Comment: Bad Luck. By chance nothing has yet overwritten the memory where it _used to be_. It could behave differently on the second sunny Tuesday of the month - or if you change one line of code somewhere else in your program. It's broken & there are no guarantees of symptoms or lack of symptoms from this mistake. All you can do is fix it & learn not to do these things.

Comment: The main thing you should do is try and drop using `char**` and pass the data back in a single buffer.  That was the original suggestion by @AviBerger.  If each individual character string doesn't contain a null, you could pass back a string of data separated with a null and terminated with a double null, then the caller is responsible for parsing the returned string properly.  That's how some Windows API functions do this, instead of trying to finagle with `char**`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I mean I don't understand c++ well at all.. could you come up with an answer in the form of the changed c++ code?

Comment: @user55665484375 -- It is a very simple concept -- The C# code gives the C++ code a large enough buffer, and the C++ code fills in the buffer.  There has to be an agreed-upon format that the C# code is looking for, and the C++ code simply places the text in the buffer that follows the agreement.   What that agreement is, that is up to you -- I merely suggested what a few Windows API functions do when having to return multiple strings.  Heck, you could return a JSON object of XML, or some other sort of format that the C# code will parse -- again, it's up to you.

Comment: We do not know what you changed the code to.  Second, this: `MyFunctions int GetData(unsigned char data[], byte* dataFromCard)` -- `memcpy(data, u8_DataFinal, sizeof(u8_DataFinal));` is a very simple example.  Also, there is nothing to try on my machine, since I know it isn't valid what you are doing (using the address of a local variable).  Maybe you are *not* doing what was suggested, and that is to *copy* the data to the buffer.  Using `=` does not do that for character pointers (as you can see, `memcpy` is used to actually do a copy).

Comment: Then of course, your C# code passes the correct type that marshalls a character array, not an `IntPtr`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie please see changes.. I think I did what you asked and it works in debug but not release c++ dll

Comment: Sometimes, you need to copy the dll file you pinvoked manually to your c# release.

Also, use an absolute path inside your dll imports instead of a fixed path.

Comment: Please fill in the array with known data, do not call any functions such as `i_Desfire.Authenticate2`, execute the `memcpy` and return.   Then this is a simple "fill in the array wth a string of characters".  If that doesn't work, then there is something fundametally wrong with how you are doing things, and you need to identify exactly where this is occurring.